# Threading and Tkinter - How to use the threading module with my simple example?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I don't understand how to use the `threading` module properly. In this example I have two tkinter widgets, a button and a progress bar. The progress bar (configured in `indeterminate` mode) has to be active when the user pushes the button, and when the task is completed, the progress bar has to be stopped.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading, ipaddress

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent=tk.Tk()
        self.parent.geometry("786x524+370+100")
        self.parent.title("Test")
        self.parent.configure(background="#f0f0f0")
        self.parent.minsize(786, 524)

        self.ProBar=ttk.Progressbar(self.parent, mode="indeterminate")
        self.ProBar.pack(padx=(40, 40), pady=(40, 40), fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.StartButton=ttk.Button(self.parent, text="Start", command=self.MyHeavyTask)
        self.StartButton.pack(padx=(40, 40), pady=(40, 40), fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.parent.mainloop()

    # my start function:
    def Start(self):
        self.ProBar.start(4)
        self.MyHeavyTask()
        self.ProBar.stop()

    # my real start function. it's just an example, it needs time to be completed:
    def MyHeavyTask(self):
        ls=[]
        obj=ipaddress.ip_network("10.0.0.0/8")
        for obj in list(obj.hosts()):
            print(obj.exploded)

# start my test:
if __name__=="__main__":
    app=MainWindow()
```

This code has an issue, it can't run the function "MyHeavyTask" and at the same time keep active the progress bar widget. to solve it, I tried to put "MyHeavyTask" in an indipendent thread changing the line 17 with this one:

```
self.StartButton=ttk.Button(self.parent, text="Start",
                            command=threading.Thread(target=self.MyHeavyTask).start())
```

unfortunately this solution doesn't work. when I press the button, nothig happens…why? What is the right way to use the `threading` module in my example?

Comment: For one thing, when you changed line 17 like that, you're starting the thread when the `StartButton` is created. See [Why is the command bound to a Button or event executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-the-command-bound-to-a-button-or-event-executed-when-declared)

Comment: Also note that you're assigning the return value from call to the thread's `start()` method to `self.StartButton`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method to the class

```
def Get_Input(self):
    message = input(">")
    if message:
        send_message(message)
```

and add in init class

```
threading.Thread(target=self.Get_Input, args=(,)).start()
```

Please note :
If you passing one argument, you need to use

```
threading.Thread(target=self.Get_Input, args=(var1,)).start()
```

Unlike common sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Here a runnable example similar to the code in your question, that shows a way to run a background task and keep a `ttk.Progressbar` active simultaneously. It does this by using the universal `after()` widget method to repeatedly schedule calls to a method that checks whether the background task is running and updates the progress bar if it is. It also disables and re-enables the <kbd>Start</kbd> button appropriately so the task can't be start again while it's running.

Note I strongly suggest you read and start following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

```
from random import randint
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
from time import sleep


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = tk.Tk()
        self.parent.geometry("786x524+370+100")
        self.parent.title("Test")
        self.parent.configure(background="#f0f0f0")
        self.parent.minsize(786, 524)

        self.task = threading.Thread(target=self.my_heavy_task)

        self.pro_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self.parent, mode="indeterminate")
        self.pro_bar.pack(padx=(40, 40), pady=(40, 40), fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.start_btn = ttk.Button(self.parent, text="Start", command=self.start)
        self.start_btn.pack(padx=(40, 40), pady=(40, 40), fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.parent.mainloop()

    def check_thread(self):
        if self.task.is_alive():
            self.pro_bar.step()  # Update progressbar.
            self.parent.after(20, self.check_thread)  # Call again after delay.
        else:
            self.pro_bar.stop()
            self.start_btn.config(state=tk.ACTIVE)

    def start(self):
        """Start heavy background task."""
        self.start_btn.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.task.start()
        self.pro_bar.start()
        self.check_thread()  # Start checking thread.

    def my_heavy_task(self):
        """Slow background task."""
        for obj in (randint(0, 99) for _ in range(6)):
            print(obj)
            sleep(.5)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = MainWindow()
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
start_thread = MainWindow()
run_test = threading.Thread(None, start_thread.start)
run_test.start()

# start my test:
if __name__=="__main__":
    app=MainWindow()
```